# Google App Scripts, Hide/Show columns based on dropdown value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a PTO leave tracker in which I want to hide/show columns based on the dropdown value.

Here is the image below, the dropdown would be the month cell "D2" enter image description here

Here is my app script code:

```
function onEdit(e) { 

    // Get the value of the dropdown selection. 
    const value = e.range.getValue("D2");

    // If the value is "January", hide columns BD:CE and CI:DM. 
    if (value === "January") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("BD:CE", "CI:QI"); 
    }

    // If the value is "February", hide columns W:BA and CI:DM, 
    else if (value === "February") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:BA", "CI:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("BD:CG"); 
    }
    else if (value === "March") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:CH", "DN:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("CI:DM"); 
    }
    else if (value === "April") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:DM", "ET:DM"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("DP:ES"); 
    }
    else if (value === "May") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:ES", "GA:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("EV:FZ"); 
    }
    else if (value === "June") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:GB", "HG:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("GC:HF"); 
    }
    else if (value === "July") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:HH", "IN:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("HI:IM"); 
    }
    else if (value === "August") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:IO", "JU:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("IP:JT"); 
    }
    else if (value === "September") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:JV", "LA:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("JW:KZ"); 
    }
    else if (value === "October") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:LB", "MH:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("LC:MG"); 
    }
    else if (value === "November") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:MI", "NN:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("MJ:NM"); 
    }
    else if (value === "December") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().hideColumns("W:NO", "OU:QI"); 
        e.source.getActiveSheet().showColumns("NP:OT"); 
    } 
}
```

---

The hide and show columns values are ok, however I get an error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')".

Could you please help me how to fix this?

I am new, and unsure what to do next.

I am new, and unsure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `onEdit` script (simple trigger) and you are capturing Event Objects with the "e" parameter. You are getting an error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')".

---

The problem is this line: `const value = e.range.getValue("D2");`

- `e.range` "represents the cell or range of cells that were edited" [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
- `getValue` doesn't accept/require a parameter. [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

But there are also other issues.

- `hideColumns("BD:CE", "CI:QI")` - `hideColumns` doesn't accept Column letters. It accepts 1) a "range", OR 2) a Column index, or 3) a Column index and number of columns) [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)
- `showColumns("BD:CG")` - `showColumn` doesn't accept Column letters. It accepts either 1) a Column Index, or 2) a Column index and number of Columns. [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex)

Lastly, there is one major flaw.

- `onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.`
- *a value* - that means "any value". So, normally an `onEdit` script will include some logic to ensure that the edited cell was on a given sheet, in a given column and/or a given row (or, as in your case, in a given cell - "D2). You don't have any such logic, you are just assuming that the edit was in cell D2, but that may not be the case.

Here's an example of how your script might be enhanced...

- the `showColumns/hideColumns` commands have been done for January - March only. The OP can convert the remainder of the months.

---

```
// create an installable onEdit trigger for this script
function showHide(e) {
  
    // Get the value of the dropdown selection. 
    var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
    var editedColumn = e.range.columnStart
    var editedSheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName()
    var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
    var editedValue = e.value
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: row="+editedRow+", column = "+editedColumn+", sheet="+editedSheetName+", value="+editedValue)
  
    
    // assume sheet = "Sheet1", cell = "D2"
    // test if 
    if (editedRow == 2 && editedColumn == 4 && editedSheetName == "Sheet1"){
    // valid row. column and sheet
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: valid cell, do stuff")
    // If the value is "January", hide columns BD:CE (56-83) and CI:DM. 
    if (editedValue === "January") {
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("BD:CE")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("CI:DM")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
    }// If the value is "February", hide columns W:BA and CI:DM, 
    else if (editedValue === "February") {
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("W:BA")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("CI:QI")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
      editedSheet.showColumns(56, 29) // bd:CG = 56-85
    }
    else if (editedValue === "March") {
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("W:CH")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
      var range = editedSheet.getRange("DN:QI")
      editedSheet.hideColumn(range)
      editedSheet.showColumns(56, 29) // bd:CG = 56-85
      editedSheet.showColumns("117,30"); 
    }
    /*
    else if (editedValue === "April") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:DM", "ET:DM"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("DP:ES"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "May") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:ES", "GA:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("EV:FZ"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "June") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:GB", "HG:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("GC:HF"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "July") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:HH", "IN:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("HI:IM"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "August") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:IO", "JU:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("IP:JT"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "September") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:JV", "LA:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("JW:KZ"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "October") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:LB", "MH:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("LC:MG"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "November") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:MI", "NN:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("MJ:NM"); 
    }
    else if (editedValue === "December") {
      editedSheet.hideColumns("W:NO", "OU:QI"); 
      editedSheet.showColumns("NP:OT"); 
    } 
    */
  }else
    {
    // one of the row/column or sheet is not value
  // do nothing
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: invalid - do nothing")
  }
}
```